# PHP SOAP Second request doesn't throw an exception

Tags: php, soap

i am trying to connect to a webservice. My webserviceHelper is:

```
class webserviceHelper {
 public function __construct($params) {

        $this->service_url = $params['service_url'];

        try {
            $this->soap = new SoapClient($this->service_url, 
                                    array('exceptions' => true));
        } 
        catch (SoapFault $exc) {
            echo 'SoapFault<br />';
            die;
        }
        catch (Exception $exc) {
            echo 'Exception<br />';
            die;
        } 
    }

    ...
}
```

When the service is down, i make a request to the page where the webserviceHelper object created. Before the response i make second request to the same page. At first one, i got "soapFault" as output but at the second, i got a fatal error.

```
Fatal error: SOAP-ERROR: Parsing WSDL: Couldn't load from 'WebService?wsdl' : failed to load external entity "WebService?wsdl" in webserviceHelper.php on line 40
```

How can i prevent this error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I handled it by using a hook in codeigniter. Thanks to the blogger. [How To Catch PHP Fatal Error In CodeIgniter](http://thecancerus.com/how-to-catch-php-fatal-error-in-codeigniter/)

Answer (score 0):

use [error_get_last()](http://php.net/manual/fr/function.error-get-last.php) after `$this->soap = new SoapClient(.....` to get potential errors

Comment: Hi, php doesnt continue to execute script after a fatal error. So this is not an option. Thanks anyway.